# Parsing error in scss file on build the application

Tags: reactjs, sass

i have an issue. with my React app while i'm building for prod.

```
./src/styles/main.scss
ParserError: Syntax Error at line: 1, column 25
```

here's my main.scss file

```
@import 'vars/typography';
@import 'vars/fonts';
@import 'vars/colors';
@import 'vars/layout';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import 'base.scss';
@import 'components/header';
@import 'components/navigation';
@import 'components/home';
@import 'components/section';
@import 'components/footer';
```

[image]

finally how i import the main.scss into my project

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './app/App';
import './styles/main.scss';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

no matter the order i'm putting the imports, i always get the same error. I tried with ./ in front of the import with the same result

Comment: parse error means your build process doesn't know what to do with the .scss file format. Did you add `node-scss`? Run `npm install node-sass --save` to add it.

Comment: I do have sass but not node-sass specifically. I'll try when I can thanks

Comment: unfortunately i get the same error

Comment: I deleted sass and node-sass and i followed that link and it works
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51850093/error-in-src-styles-scss-module-build-failed-error-cannot-find-module-no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @dikuw for the answer.
To wrap up, I deleted Sass and node-sass and I followed that link for cleaning and rebuilding the whole project.

[ERROR in ./src/styles.scss .. Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51850093/error-in-src-styles-scss-module-build-failed-error-cannot-find-module-no)